# ebase,URI Added to my URL. How to replace?

Tags: wordpress, seo

I'm facing this weird issue on my WordPress site.  I'm using SEOPress for my SEO stuff and generate an error saying

> https://www.sitename.com/blog/xyzpath/e,baseURI

But if I remove the `e,baseURI` everything works fine.  Mostly this happens in my blog pages and my permalinks structure looks like

> /%category%/%postname%/

I don't know where it comes from and don't know how to get rid of this.